# Is it possible to use relative paths in sphinx.conf?

Tags: sphinx

I'm using Sphinx on a Linux production server as well as a Windows dev machine running WampServer.

The index configurations in `sphinx.conf` each require a `path` setting for the output file name. Because the filesystems on the production server and dev machine are different, I have to have two lines and then comment one out depending on which server I'm using.

```
#path           = /path/to/folder/name #LIVE
path           = C:\wamp\www\site\path\to\folder\name #LOCALHOST
```

Since I have lots of indexes, it gets really old having to constantly comment and uncomment dozens of lines every time I need to update the file.

Using relative paths would be the ideal solution, but when I tried that I received the following error when running the indexer:

> FATAL: failed to open ../folder/name.tmp.spl: Invalid argument, will not index. Try --rotate option.

Is it possible to use relative paths in sphinx.conf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **can** use relative paths, but its kind of tricky because you the various utilities will have different working directories.

eg On windows the searchd service, will start IIRC with a working directory of $WINDIR$\System32

on linux, via crontab, I think it has working directory left over from previously, so would have to change the folder in the actual command line

... ie its not relative to the config file, its relative to the current working directory.

---

Personally I use a version control system (SVN actually) to manage it. The version from Dev, is always the one commited to the repository, the 'working copy' on the LIVE server, has had the paths edited to the right location. So when 'update' to the latest file, only changes are merged leaving the local filepaths in tact.

---

Other people use a dynamic config file. The config file can be a script (php/python/perl etc) - but this only works on linux so wont help you.

---

Or can just have a 'publish' script. Basically, you edit a 'master' config file, and one that can be freely copied to all servers. Then a 'publish' script, that writes the apprirate local path. It could do it with some pretty simple search replace.

```
<?php 

if (trim(`hostname`) == 'live') {
  $path = '/path/to/folder/';
} else {
  $path = 'C:\wamp\www\site\path\to\folder\`;
}

$contents = file_get_contents('sphinx.conf.master');
$contents = str_replace('$path',$path,$contents);
file_put_contents('sphinx.conf',$contents);
```

Then have `path = $path\name` in the master config file, which will get replaced to the proper path, when run the script on the local machine